# Is it possible to set up a subsite, which members of the parent site cannot access?

Tags: permissions, sub-site

We definitely want members of the subsite to access the parent site, but not necessarily the other way round.  Is this easy to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible, the sub-site has its own Permissions and you can setup its unique permissions so that the users you want have access to sub-site [not all of them]

You simply need to play with Site Settings -> Permissions when in sub-site!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you  have to break role inherticance in subsites

with powershell here:
http://marcboes.wordpress.com/2011/03/02/break-inheritance-for-sub-sites-and-remove-visitor-role/

with the GUI I guess its possible as well.